# Python - How to check if socket is still connected

Tags: python, sockets, networking, tcp, tcpclient

I have the following code, which is self explanatory:

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(host, port)
s.send("some data")
# don't close socket just yet... 
# do some other stuff with the data (normal string operations)
if s.stillconnected() is true:
    s.send("some more data")
if s.stillconnected() is false:
    # recreate the socket and reconnect
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect(host, port)
    s.send("some more data")
s.close()
```

How do I implement `s.stillconnected()`
I do not wish to recreate the socket blindly.

Comment: Good job +1 but see comments on your bounty here: https://superuser.com/questions/955266/prevent-windows-7-sleep-while-files-are-being-accessed-by-network and let me know if anything in those comments would be helpful.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If the server connection is no longer alive, calling the send method will throw an exception, so you can use a try-exception block to attempt to send data, catch the exception if it's thrown, and reestablish the connection:

```
try:
    s.send("some more data")
except:
    # recreate the socket and reconnect
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect(host, port)
    s.send("some more data")
```

**EDIT**: As per @Jean-Paul Calderone's comments, please consider using the `sendall` method, which is a higher level method that sends all the data or throws an error, instead of `send`, which is a lower level method that does not guarantee the transmission of all the data, OR use higher level modules like an HTTP library that can handle socket lifecycles.

Comment: is there a more efficient way without using try/except block that you can implement the stillConnected() function with? ; if so please add it to the your answer

Comment: Glad it worked :) At the moment, this is the best way I can think of. If you're receiving data, you can also try a while loop that keeps on receiving data, until an empty string is received when the connection terminates.

Comment: Don't forget that `send` is not guaranteed to send the whole byte string passed to it.  Calling `send` without checking the return value (which tells you how many bytes were sent) is basically always wrong.

Comment: @Jean-PaulCalderone so by that you mean we should receive data immediately after sending, and then perform checks?

Comment: `sent_length = socket.send(data); if sent_length < len(data): some_retransmit_logic()`.  Or `socket.sendall(data)` which has retransmit logic built-in.

Comment: Or possibly use a higher level module than the socket module since there's really no need to re-implement low-level socket logic in 99.9% of projects.

Comment: For example, use an HTTP library which manages socket lifetimes for you.  Then just send requests instead of worrying about whether your sockets are still connected.

Comment: @Jean-PaulCalderone thanks. Updated the answer to include your input.

Comment: Very very bad not putting which error you are excepting. At least just in case use `except Exception as error` or `except BaseException as error` even if you are not interested of catching it but at least log in DEBUG level

Answer (score 22):

I've had good results with this variant to check if a socket is closed (negate the result if you want to check if it's still connected):

```py
import logging
import socket


logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


def is_socket_closed(sock: socket.socket) -> bool:
    try:
        # this will try to read bytes without blocking and also without removing them from buffer (peek only)
        data = sock.recv(16, socket.MSG_DONTWAIT | socket.MSG_PEEK)
        if len(data) == 0:
            return True
    except BlockingIOError:
        return False  # socket is open and reading from it would block
    except ConnectionResetError:
        return True  # socket was closed for some other reason
    except Exception as e:
        logger.exception("unexpected exception when checking if a socket is closed")
        return False
    return False
```

Comment: Neat solution, but it doesn't seem to be working on Windows, due to the socket.MSG_* flags unavailable on it.

Comment: @manu3d On windows you can alternatively use sock.setblocking(0) before recv

Comment: @benlev That doesn't solve the peeking problem